# I get segmentation fault whenever I try to use NPM or nodejs. Uninstalling and reinstalling doesn't fix it

Tags: node.js, npm

I tried to update nodejs using the following:

```
$ sudo npm cache clean -f
$ sudo npm install -g n
$ sudo n stable
```

I have always successfully used this to update nodejs, however, the update failed this time. Now, whenever I run NPM or nodejs, I get a segmentation fault.

I tried uninstalling NPM and nodejs using many variations of:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge npm
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs
sudo apt-get remove --purge node
```

And reinstalling them.

However, they never seem to uninstall. Whenever I type NPM or node, it says permission denied. When I use sudo, I get a segmentation fault.

`$ which npm` results in `/usr/local/bin/npm`
and I get similar results with nodejs.

Is there a simple way to fix this? I'm very leery about manually removing packages. I've tried this on a personal machine in the past and messed up the package manager so badly that I had no choice but to reinstall Ubuntu. I would like to avoid doing that since this is on a development server.

Answer (score 0):

The node binary was corrupt and Ubuntu was unable to unstall/uninstall node using the apt package manager. To solve this issue I just copied the node 12.13.0 binary file from another machine into /usr/local/bin on this machine. Now node and all node related modules (such as npm) work perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem , and simply fix it by :
`apt update`
then
`apt upgrade`
- HOPE THIS HELP -

Answer (score 0):

just remove nodejs, use

```
sudo apt-get remove nodejs
```

then go to **/usr/local/bin** and remove node, nodejs npm if exists:

```
sudo rm nodejs 
sudo rm npm 
sudo rm node
```

reinstall nodejs with this link https://computingforgeeks.com/install-latest-node-js-and-npm-on-ubuntu-debian/